# difficult css styling: button alignment AND changing fieldnames AND dynamic text length

Tags: javascript, html, css

What i want is the fieldnames of each radio button set is flexible, it could range from 10-30 char for instance, but the radio button position for the first and second row must be aligned as seen below. Also, the radio button names may change, so is there a way to maintain the alignment despite having changes in the radio button names. Seems like the max in German is 4 chars ('Nein') and 2 chars ('Ja') and different numbers for English.

**So is there a generic way in IE to maintain the radio button alignment between the first and second row, and also align the fields names? A good example is below:**

[image]

What i did with my css style sheet is to attempt the above styling but my indentation as a fixed length of space in front of each field name has caused the radio buttons to be misaligned. **Below is my current code result:**

[image: My current code]

**My css code**

```
.sRRBA { font-family:Arial;color:#000000;font-size:9pt; margin-left:190px }
.sRRBJ { font-family:Arial;color:#000000;font-size:9pt; margin-left:190px }
.sRRCI { font-family:Arial;color:#000000;font-size:9pt; margin-left:190px }
.sRRDH { font-family:Arial;color:#000000;font-size:9pt; margin-left:190px }
```

**View Source html code**

```
<span class="sRRBA">Customer Marketing Permission Postal Address</span>



               <input type="radio" name="" value="N" />
               <span class="readonlytext">No</span>

               <input type="radio" name="" value="Y" />
               <span class="readonlytext">Yes</span>

         <span class="sRRBJ">Customer Marketing Permission Telephone</span>



               <input type="radio" name="" value="N" />
               <span class="readonlytext">No</span>

               <input type="radio" name="" value="Y" />
               <span class="readonlytext">Yes</span>

         <span class="sRRCI">Customer Marketing Permission Mobile Phone</span>



               <input type="radio" name="" value="N" />
               <span class="readonlytext">No</span>

               <input type="radio" name="" value="Y" />
               <span class="readonlytext">Yes</span>

         <span class="sRRDH">Customer Marketing Permission Email</span>



               <input type="radio" name="" value="N" />
               <span class="readonlytext">No</span>

               <input type="radio" name="" value="Y" />
               <span class="readonlytext">Yes</span>


      </div>
```

Comment: This looks like a job for tables! I know, they're evil, but you're just trying to line up simple elements.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney i'm using making the styling in XSL, which gets data from XML, and i undergo XSLT and our in-house generation process to create .jsp pages which form the client-side stuff. for tables, do you have anything to suggest for a complex process such as mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways you could do this.  Here are two.

You could put each column into its own  tag and each column would be floated left and set to display inline-block.  Then each column would line up.  For example:

```
.topcontainer {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ecolumn {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 6px;
 }

<div class="topcontainer">
    <div class="ecolumn">
        <div>Line1</div>
        <div>Line2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ecolumn">
        <div><input...></div>
        <div><input...></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this approach is that it won't line up vertically if the lines are different heights.  You can get around this by setting explicit heights on your div elements.  It's also possible if you have the screen room, to insert a non-breaking space (&nbsp;) in there to level the height with the font.  You could also set height to 1em to match the font height in use.

You could also use a table -- that's really the only way to line up both rows and columns perfectly without specifying widths and heights.  Tables have other issues, such as confusing content consumers such as screen readers, so it's up to you:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Line1</td>
            <td><input...></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Line2</td>
            <td><input...></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit:**

In response to your comment, I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for so here's some general info.

HTML Tables always take the smallest space they need unless you set their width in some way.  You could set the table width and set the left column to 100% width to get the effect you are looking for.  You could also set a pixel width on the first column only, or you could set the items you are putting into the left column to have a right-margin so that they take up more space in the cell.  There are other methods too; it all depends on exactly what effect you are looking for.

Also, you can set styles on each cell in the table to align the contents left, right, center, top, bottom, middle.

Comment: hi i did the above, but how do i make the td elements align towards the right, while maintaining alignment with each other? right now, when i reduce the word-length, the td elements keep moving towards the left

Comment: I added more information to my answer.  If that doesn't answer your question, just be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would created classes for each column giving each a width and setting display type to inline-block. Then div up your columns and set their class to the 'column' classes you just made.